# Apple Developer APNs Role

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, app-store-connect

We're attempting to figure out what role is necessary for a user to have to generate an APNs certificate through the Apple Developer Portal.  It appears that we currently have Developer role, and that this isn't enough (the only certificates that appear are for signing).  We have another account that has an Admin role which does have access, but we want to be certain that an Admin role is required, as we'd prefer to request least permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Setting up APNS with either TLS or autentication tokens require either the *Account Holder* or *Admin* role.

Can you add or enable the Account Holder role on your Developer account?

Here are a couple of links about APNS authentication types:

[Communicate with APNs using authentication tokens](https://help.apple.com/developer-account/#/deva05921840)

[Communicate with APNs using a TLS certificate](https://help.apple.com/developer-account/#/dev82a71386a)

Here is some more info about roles:

[Program Roles](https://developer.apple.com/support/roles/)

Hope this helps!  Getting APNS set up is always a chore.